# datepicker - open popup by clicking a href tag

Tags: datepicker, form-submit, href

I wonder how I can call the datepicker script from a link, something like

```
<div id="datepicker_popup"><a href="#">Choose Date</a></div>
```

and submit the chosen date to a PHP page. Any ideas? Thanx, chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css to format the textbox to look like a normal link. That way you'd not need to play about with it that much? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Jquery [datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker)